# Concise nested statements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I really like the ruby `?` `:` syntax for `if`/`else` statements.

However, I'm not sure how to do the following with a nested statement:

```
if information.is_empty?
  if leader? || possessor?
    link_to('update ' + contextual('your') + ' credentials!', edit_user_path) 
  else
    user.name + ' hasn\'t entered this info!'
  end
else
  information        
end
```

Should I bother? Does the `?` `:` syntax (for want of a term!) actually make code pretty unreadable and non-self-documenting?

If you think I should use the `?` `:` syntax, how would I tackle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The `?:` is called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's not specific to Ruby; a lot of languages have it (in fact, I believe I linked you to that wikipedia page in a comment [very recently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47330/14370)).
2. Go easy on the newlines; there's a lot of whitespace there (update: question was edited; now it's gone)
3. Use string interpolation
4. [We've talked about](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47330/14370) that `is_` prefix on `?` methods already :)

To answer your question: Ternaries have their use, but like everything else, they can also be abused.

In practice, there's no difference between a ternary and and a good ol' `if...else`, so you can use either - but that argument goes both ways. Don't use ternaries *just because you can*.

A good case for a ternary (in my opinion), would be something like this (just as an example):

```
puts some_boolean_value ? "yes" : "no"
```

or something like

```
"You have #{messages.count} new #{messages.one? ? 'message' : 'messages'}"
```

There's no logic going on in either the `if` or the `else` branch, and both are very short, so it's short and sweet to use a ternary.

In Ruby you can also spell the first one out like:

```
puts if some_boolean_value
  "yes"
else
  "no"
end
```

It's neat that Ruby treats `if...else` as an expression, but here it seems like a waste of space for something so simple.

**In your case:** Your code *does* have more branching logic, so I'd definitely avoid ternaries, and keep it as-is. Personally, I'd *never* nest ternary expressions inside each other, just for readability reasons.

Alternatively, you can return early (assuming this code is in a method):

```
return information unless information.is_empty?

if leader? || possessor?
  link_to("update #{contextual "your"} credentials", edit_user_path)
else
  "#{user.name} hasn't entered this info!"
end
```

If you wrote it *all* in ternaries, it'd be pretty ridiculous:

```
information.is_empty? ? leader? || professor? ? link_to("update #{contextual "your"} credentials", edit_user_path) : "#{user.name} hasn't entered this info!" : information # what?
```

The middle road would be to use a ternary for the innermost nested branch only

```
if information.is_empty?
  leader? || professor? ? link_to("update #{contextual "your"} credentials", edit_user_path) : "#{user.name} hasn't entered this info!"
else
  information
end
```

But, as you can see, that innermost nested branch is also the one with the most going on, so it's still less readable than a normal `if...else`

Comment: I think you did something strange in some of the examples; syntax highlighting looks wrong (although I don't know ruby)

Comment: @Izkata Should be fine. The highlighting is just stumbling over the string-inside-a-string in the string interpolations. It's basically `"text #{ruby code with a string in it} more text"` and the syntax highlighter doesn't understand that

Answer (score 3):

I think that the key concern should be clarity.  Specifically, I recommend eliminating the nesting, which would make it clear that one of three branches will be taken no matter what.

In addition…

- Standard Ruby style uses two spaces of indentation.
- `is_empty?` is a redundant name.  The question mark alone is enough to convey the fact that it is a predicate.
- Use less clumsy string quoting.

```
if !information.empty?
  information
elsif leader? || possessor?
  link_to("update #{contextual('your')} credentials!", edit_user_path) 
else
  "#{user.name} hasn't entered this info!"
end
```

You *could* write that using a ternary expression, but I would advise against it on readability grounds.

Comment: I see the `leader? || professor?` thing as orthogonal to whether there's any information. For a litmus test: You can't swap the branches around in your code and get the same result (not saying that's a great test, but just as an example)